# Multiple WPF Windows using same Resource simultaneous

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, resourcedictionary

I had an strange Bug in my application. Whenever the AboutDialog would be displayed the companylogo on the mainwindow vanished.

I have the discovered that this is related to multiple windows using the same resource simultaneous.
In my testapplication I am starting two windows like this:

```
void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
  mainWindow.Top = 100;
  mainWindow.Left = 900;
  mainWindow.Show();
}
```

On my Mainwindow I am using a ContentPresenter with a path stored as Application resource. This does not happen with a string. But my logo is only displayed on one Window.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Logo" Content="{DynamicResource BrandingLogo}" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="{DynamicResource MyConstString}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Edit:

In my real-world-application my logo is stored in a ResourceDictionary so it is not possible to set x:Shared to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `x:Shared = false` on the `Canvas` resource to return the new instance everytime.

```
   <Canvas x:Key="BrandingLogo" x:Shared = "false"/>
```

Comment: This is very good and would work if my Resource would not be located in a ResourceDictionary.  -.-

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776631/using-x-shared-in-a-resourcedictionary-prevents-you-from-setting-the-file-build-action-to-resource

Comment: Yes, i will get following exception when trying to load my ResourceDictionary.

XamlParseException:
Shared attribute in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' can be used only in compiled resource dictionaries.

Comment: what is the buildaction of your dictionary?

Comment: buildaction is Resource

Comment: as the workaround stated.. can you try changing it to Page and try again with x:Shared